# Meteor.js Collection empty on Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

Why is it that `myCollection.find().fetch()` returns an empty array `[]` even though the call is made within `if(data){...}`? Doesn't the `if` statement ensure that the collection has been retrieved before executing the `console.log()`?

```
Template.chart.rendered = function() {

        var data = myCollection.find().fetch();

        if(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }

        $('#chart').render();

}
```

This returns `[]` in the browser Javascript console.

Comment: The question was rather, why Meteor is returning empty collection. I suppose you are not publishing it in right way or you don't do it at all. Post the code so, we will be able to help.

Comment: @Jagi `auto-publish` has not been removed, and doing `console.log(myCollection.find().count())` returns a positive number in the browser Javascript console.

Comment: In my case, the tuorial I was following assumed `autopublish` to be installed. But the version I installed didn't have that package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `count()` instead which returns the number of results. `data` itself would be an empty array, `[]` which isn't falsey ( `[] == true` ).

Also don't use `fetch()` unless you're going to use the raw data for it because its quite taxing. You can loop through it with `.forEach` if you need to.

```
var data = myCollection.find();

if(data.count())
  console.log(data);

//If you need it for something/Not sure if this is right but just an example
$('#chart').render(data.fetch())
```

Comment: Thanks, somehow `data.count()` in the suggested code returns `0`, while doing `data.count()` in the browser Javascript console returns the correct count. So the collection data is stil not fetched. Using something other than `rendered` in `Template.chart.rendered` appeared to hep avoid this problem, why is that?

Comment: Its happening because the code is running too early. When meteor initially loads there's no data in and it comes in a bit later (about a second later). You would have to tie it up to the subscription functions so that it fires after the template is rendered and the data is available

Comment: Or use `Deps.autorun` instead if you know you're on the correct page

Comment: @Akshat could you mention a correct pattern to do the first approach?  My situation is that I need to extend some of the object of the collection (randomly), to tag them as active for a carrousel. Sometimes _.extends receives an empty list as result of find().fetch()

Comment: I got what you meant. Hold On. :) leaving the link for other spaced out alien http://docs.meteor.com/#publishandsubscribe

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have to wait for data from the server. When you just use `Template.name.rendered` function it is immediately invoked. You have to use `Template.name.helpers` function to wait for data from the server. Everything is described in the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_helpers).

Answer (score 2):

It seems when you "remove autopublish" you have to also subscribe on the client.

```
  if(Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.startup(function() {
      Myvars = new Mongo.Collection("myvars");
      Meteor.subscribe('myvars')
    });
  }
```

and enable allow and publish on the server

```
  if(Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
      Myvars = new Mongo.Collection("myvars");
      Myvars.allow({
        insert: function () {
          return true;
        },
        update: function () {
          return true;
        },
        remove: function () {
          return true;
        }
      });
      if (Myvars.find().count() == 0) {
        Myvars.insert({myvalue:'annoyed'});
      }

      Meteor.publish("myvars", function() {
        return Myvars.find();
      });
    });
  }
```

I'm new to this as well. I was just looking to have a global value that all clients could share. Seems like a useful idea (from a beginner's perspective) and a complete oversight on the Meteor teams behalf, it was nowhere clearly documented in this way. I also still have no idea what allow fetch is, that too is completely unclear in the official documentation.

Comment: you can leave out the `== 0`

Answer (score 1):

It does, but in javascript you have the following strange behaviour

```
if ([]){
  console.log('Oops it goes inside the if')
} // and it will output this, nontheless it is counter-intuitive
```

This happens because JS engine casts `Boolean([])`  to `true`. You can how different types are [casted to Boolean here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean).

Check if your array is not empty in the beginning.

```
a = [];
if (a.length){
  //do your thing
}
```

Comment: `data` appears to be `[]` when the template helper code is executed, causing the collection data to be missing. However when `console.log(myCollection.find().count()` is executed in the Javascript console, it does show a count of all the documents retrieved for the query.