# Calling find() with a collection returns nothing even though the collection has data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, coffeescript

I am trying to make an extremely simple Meteor app that is almost exactly the same as the tutorial. I am simply trying to return all the elements from a collection. I am using autopublish.

My code looks like this. I am using coffeescript, but I tried using JavaScript and there was no change.

```
    @Studies = new Mongo.Collection "studies"

    if Meteor.isClient
        console.log "Is client"
        Template.find.helpers
            studies: ->
                console.log "client"
                console.log Studies.find().fetch()
                return Studies.find()
```

When I load the page, "client" is logged and "[]" is logged after. However, when I run mongo in terminal, I run "db.studies.find()" and what is returned is

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId("56601b66ab1ba5a30d2d94c7"), "title" : "study 1" }
```

What am I doing wrong? I really appreciate your help in advance, as I have been stuck on this for hours now.

Comment: Maybe this anwer can help you in the good direction: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28891421/4278038

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, I am using autopublish so there shouldn't be an issue with publishing.

Comment: Still, it's probably caused because the code is running too early (before the autopublish has completed). Another related question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20210212/4278038

Comment: I tried logging count in the code and after the site loaded. Both times, it returned 0. I think that means that the timing isn't the issue here, and there's something else that's wrong. What do you think?

Comment: Well, if you are sure you have `autopublish` and some data in the collection... it should work. Could you please create a [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/) to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: @McVenco it would surely run before publish completed, but it would also rerun when data would be available

Comment: You inserted the values using the mongo prompt, and now they have `ObjectId`s for an `_id`. Try to use the server shell (`meteor shell`) to insert the documents and see if that helps. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33971972/268093) for more details.

Comment: @MasterAM Thank you so much!!!! I used the shell and inserting it worked! Thanks to everyone else as well!